# On cycloids and other roulettes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

It is well known that the cycloid is the curve traced by a point on a circle as the circle rolls along a line without slipping.

1. Consider wheels with smooth convex shapes (not necessarily circular) all of the same perimeter being rolled along a line. Is the area of an arch of the resulting roulette curve an extremum when the wheel is a circle - and the roulette is a cycloid?

Note 1: If the wheel is not a circle, the trajectories of different points on the boundary would be different although each trajectory consists of arches of same base length (equal to perimeter of the wheel) - eg: if an ellipse is rolled, the ends of the major axis would trace arches of height 2a and no other point rises so high. So, above question should be be about the average among the area under the arches traced by all the points.

2. Is there any smooth convex shape for a wheel such that when rolled along a straight line, a point on its rim traces out the arc of a circle?

Note 2: question 2 could be whether *any one point on the rim of some smooth wheel* traces arches that are perfect circular arcs OR whether there is some smooth wheel such that every point on its rim traces arches that are circular arcs.

Note 3: Question 2 could be extended by seeking wheel shapes for which each arch of the roulette is segment of a catenary, parabola, etc. instead of circular arc..

Comment: As far as the second question, one can't have the *entire* roulette be an arc of a circle because, where the point touches down on the line, the roulette is parametrized in the form $$\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr) = \left(\frac{\kappa^2}6\,s^3+\cdots,\ \frac{\kappa}2\, s^2+ \cdots\ \right), $$ (where $\kappa$ is the curvature of the convex curve at the tracing point), and this implies that the curvature of the roulette goes to infinity at $s=0$. One *can* arrange (by solving a differential equation) that part of the roulette be an arc of a circle, but just how large an arc is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Will at least a semicircle be possible as a roulette? For a sequence of semicircular arches, at the cusps, the point of the wheel in contact with the line seems to be totally at rest (unlike for other arcs where the velocity of the contact point along the line of motion seems nonzero at cusps).

Comment: A whole semicircle is not possible with a smooth (strictly) convex curve.  Whenever the roulette touches the line, it will look like the formula above for some $\kappa$.  Notice that $\bigl(x'(0),y'(0)\bigr) = (0,0)$, so the point does actually 'stop' when it gets down to the line, i.e., when $y(s)=0$, but $x(s)$ does not 'turn around' there; it just pauses and then goes on.  I expect that you can get quite close to a semi-circle, maybe except on an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the 'touchdown' points.

Comment: @R Nandakumar: For the second question the kinematical relation $s^2+R^2=a^2$ (s=arc, R= radius of curvature) yields spiral roulettes (on numerical integration) for circular arc traces of curvature center. The center of a  rolling circular arc traces a straight line anyhow.

Comment: @Narasimham, I hadn't thought about points not on the rim of the wheel and the *trochoids*.  As you point out,  the center of a circular wheel will trace a straight line. Based on Prof. Bryant's answer, I suspect even if we examine curtate trochoids (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochoid) resulting from noncircular wheels, we wouldn't get a sequence of circular arcs.

Comment: Choosing a *different* base line (instead of straight) as a circle, there seems to be a possibility. When a moving involute gear wheel M rolls externally on another fixed involute gear wheel tooth F without sliding, *any* point on M would trace out a circular arc as roulette locus.This is a start point but can however be tweaked a bit towards a rack.